# How to stop FB page likes from showing up in friends' news feeds?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

There are some Facebook pages that I want to "like", but I don't want my Facebook friends to know that I liked them.  Facebook seems to show all your page likes in your friends' news feeds, though.  I am OK with my friends going to my profile page and seeing all the pages that I have liked, I just don't want my page likes to appear in their news feeds.  Any way to prevent that from happening?